# How do you create a button that changes the image to the next image in an image array

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

I have an assignment that requires me to code a website using HTML and JavaScript. The Website is just a very basic website (I'm a Computer Science Student just starting HTML) about the planet in the solar system.

The website includes two buttons, as you'll see in the below code, that change the text on the screen to the next planet in the solar system however sometimes when the buttons are clicked this doesn't occur, instead the text changes to the incorrect planet or simply states "undefined" until the button is clicked a few more times when the website will continue to work correctly.

Here's my code:

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="cyan">
<h1>The Solar System</h1>
<script>
var planets= ["Mercury","Venus","Earth","Mars","Jupiter","Saturn","Uranus","Neptune"];
var endofplanets=planets.length;
var i =0;

function nextplanet(){
if (i<endofplanets){
document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML=planets[i];
i++;
}

}
</script>
<script>
function previousplanet(){
if (i>-1){
document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML=planets[i];
i--;
}

}
</script>
<p id="p1">---</p>
<button type="button" onclick=nextplanet()>Next Planet</button>
<button type="button" onclick=previousplanet()>Previous Planet</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.. simple solution

```html
<html>
<body bgcolor="cyan">
<h1>The Solar System</h1>
<script>
var planets= ["Mercury","Venus","Earth","Mars","Jupiter","Saturn","Uranus","Neptune"];
var endofplanets=planets.length;

var i = -1;

function nextplanet()
{
  i=i+1;

  if(i==endofplanets){
    i=0;
  }

document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML=planets[i];

}

function previousplanet(){

  i=i-1;
  if(i<0){
    i=endofplanets-1;}

  document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML=planets[i];


}
</script>
<p id="p1">---</p>
<button type="button" onclick="nextplanet()">Next Planet</button>
<button type="button" onclick="previousplanet()">Previous Planet</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try adding some explanation as well.

Comment: Thanks, this certainly is simpler

Answer (score 0):

check this:- you need to add else condition in next button and reset i value to 0, this is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3bsyypL9/2/

```
    <html>
<body bgcolor="cyan">
<h1>The Solar System</h1>
<script>
var planets= ["Mercury","Venus","Earth","Mars","Jupiter","Saturn","Uranus","Neptune"];
var endofplanets=planets.length;
var i =0;

function nextplanet(){
if (i<endofplanets){
document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML=planets[i];
i++;
}
else
{
i = 0;
document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML=planets[i];
i++;
}

}
</script>
<script>
function previousplanet(){
if (i>0){
i--;
document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML=planets[i];

}

}
</script>
<p id="p1">---</p>
<button type="button" onclick="nextplanet()">Next Planet</button>
<button type="button" onclick="previousplanet()">Previous Planet</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction however the problem still persists, if the user presses the "Previous planet" button in the middle of the planets it always goes to the next planet in the array before it goes back.

Comment: Again, thanks but the previous planet button still causes the text to go to the next planet and then, when the button is pressed again, the previous planet will show.

Answer (score 0):

The answer of DHRUV GUPTA contain an error, when i equals 7, if you do nextplanet() then i is increased by one. So if you trigger the function previousplanet(), i is equal to 8 and you get an undefined result.

The simplest way to avoid this error is to not increase i everytime.
Check this :
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZbBVX

**NO LOOP VERSION**

```
i = -1; //To be sure that the first planet will be Mercury

function nextplanet(){
    if (i<endofplanets){
        i = Math.min(i+1,endofplanets-1); //Take the minimum between i+1 and last indice of your array (7), so i will ever be lower of equal to the max indice of your array
        document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML=planets[i];
    }
}

function previousplanet(){
    if (i>-1){
        i = Math.max(i-1,0); //The same, i will be ever greater or equal to 0, which is the lower indice of your array ;)
        document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML=planets[i];
    }
}
```

**LOOP VERSION**

```
i = 0;

function nextplanet(){
    document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML=planets[i];
    i = (i+1) % endofplanets; //With a modulo, your indice is always between 0 and endofplanets-1, google modulo if you don't know this operator ;)
}

function previousplanet(){
     document.getElementById('p1').innerHTML=planets[i];
     i = (i-1) % endofplanets;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this has been driving me daft for the last 2 days, can't thank you enough. If possible could you explain what the Math.min and Math.max lines do. Thanks again

Comment: your code does not go to next planet, when its on last, should go on first, too complex.

Comment: Romanric Mollard's answer works for me, the code does exactly what I need it to do. However, if anybody can explain to me what the Math.min and Math.max lines do I'd be very grateful

Comment: I added the loop version, shorter using a modulo. But you're right, the no loop version is a bit complex, I'll update it. Anyway you always have an error in your response : test with next, next and previous. You will have to click twice the previous button to get the previous planet.

R Rodriguez, I'm on it

Comment: Thanks again but i'm gonna stick to the no loop version as I don't understand a lot of the code in the loop  version which will be a problem when I come to do an evaluation for my classwork. Thanks anyway

Comment: I added some comments. Don't hesitate if you don't understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot, didn't think that the people on this website could be so helpful. Thanks for all your time